# Cómo quitar los campos repetidos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen dia, tengo una duda. Resulta que tengo los siguientes campos repetidos, se supone que tiene que imprimir el valor deseado pero no crear esos campos con ceros de mas, alguien sabria a que se debe? 
Agradezco muchisimo por su colaboración

```
  <?php
         $dias=0;
         $salir='';
         $i=0;      
         $ter_co1=0;    
         $v_spe=0;  
         $v_pve=0;  
         $v_v5=0;
         $v_ven_t=0;
         $orden=isset($_POST['radio'])? $_POST['radio'] : '';   
         $tip_men='';       
         $dif_fec=0;
         $dias=0;    
         $ordenar='';   
         $sald=0;***
         $nom_pr=isset($_POST['proveedor'])? $_POST['proveedor'] : '';  
         $mon_pr=isset($_POST['moneda'])? $_POST['moneda'] : '';
     switch($orden)
      {



        case 0: $ordenar=" ORDER BY D.PVD_NOMB ASC,B.FAC_FEFA ASC"; break; 
        case 1: $ordenar=" ORDER BY B.FAC_FEFA ASC,D.PVD_NOMB DESC"; break; 
        case 2: $ordenar=" ORDER BY B.MON_CODI ASC,A.CXP_SALD DESC,D.PVD_NOMB DESC"; break; 
        case 3: $ordenar=" "; break; 
     }


    switch($mon_pr)
      {
        case 'Pesos': $sc_pro=" AND B.MON_CODI='1'"; break; 
        case 'Dolar': $sc_pro=" AND B.MON_CODI='2'"; break; 
        case '': $sc_pro=""; break; 
     }

    if (!empty($nom_pr))
    {
        $sc_pro=" AND D.PVD_NOMB='$nom_pr'";
    }
         $qcon100="SELECT  D.PVD_CODA NIT,D.PVD_NOMB NOM,B.MON_CODI mon,A.CXP_SALD SALD,B.TOP_CODI top1,B.FAC_NUME doc,
         B.FAC_FEFA doc_fec,A.CXP_FEVE doc_ven,CXP_DESC,A.CXP_SALD,B.FAC_TIPO doc_tip,G.COC_NOMB
 from 
 PROVEEDOR_MARCA E,PO_CXPAG A, PO_FACTU B,GN_DCOCO C,PO_PVDOR D,GN_COCOM G
 WHERE E.PVD_CODI=A.PVD_CODI
 AND A.EMP_CODI=B.EMP_CODI
 AND B.EMP_CODI=C.EMP_CODI
 AND B.EMP_CODI=G.EMP_CODI
 AND A.EMP_CODI=D.EMP_CODI
 AND A.PVD_CODI=D.PVD_CODI
 AND A.FAC_CONT=B.FAC_CONT
 AND B.COC_CODI=G.COC_CODI
 $sc_pro
 AND A.CXP_SALD>0
 and B.FAC_TIPO='F'

 group by B.FAC_NUME,D.PVD_CODA,D.PVD_NOMB,B.MON_CODI,A.CXP_SALD,B.TOP_CODI,B.FAC_FEFA,A.CXP_FEVE,CXP_DESC,A.CXP_SALD,B.FAC_TIPO,G.COC_NOMB
 $ordenar";
            $acon100=odbc_exec($conn, $qcon100);
        for($f00=0;$bcon100=odbc_fetch_row($acon100);$f00++)
        { 
            $ter_co=odbc_result($acon100,"NIT");
            if (empty($ter_co1))
            {
                $ter_co1=$ter_co;
            }
            if ($ter_co1==$ter_co)
            {
            $prov=odbc_result($acon100,"NOM");  
            $pl_pr=odbc_result($acon100,"COC_NOMB"); 
            $doc_fec=odbc_result($acon100,"doc_fec");
            $doc_tip=odbc_result($acon100,"doc_tip");
            $doc_ven=odbc_result($acon100,"doc_ven");   
            $doc=odbc_result($acon100,"doc");           
            $top=odbc_result($acon100,"top1");
            $doc_val=odbc_result($acon100,"SALD");
            $mon=odbc_result($acon100,"mon");

            $sel1="select * from orden_pago_prov where fac_nume='$doc'";
            $asel1=odbc_exec($conn, $sel1);
            $doc_pag=odbc_result($asel1,"fac_nume");    
            $ord_pag=odbc_result($asel1,"pago_orden");
            $ord_pag_f=odbc_result($asel1,"pago_fecha");    
            $ord_val=odbc_result($asel1,"pago_valor");

            if ($ord_pag_f=='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
            {
                $ord_pag_f='';
            }

            switch($pl_pr){
                case 'PROVEEDORES 8 DIAS': $dia_pl=8; break;
                case 'PROVEEDORES 15 DIAS': $dia_pl=15; break;
                case 'PROVEEDORES 30 DIAS': $dia_pl=30; break;
                case 'PROVEEDORES 45 DIAS': $dia_pl=45; break;
                case 'PROVEEDORES 60 DIAS': $dia_pl=60; break;
                case 'PROVEEDORES 90 DIAS': $dia_pl=90; break;
                case 'PROVEEDORES 75 DIAS': $dia_pl=75; break;
                case '20 DIAS': $dia_pl=20; break;
                case '40 DIAS': $dia_pl=40; break;
            }           

            $doc_fec1=date("Y-m-d",  mktime(0,0,0,substr($doc_fec,5,2),substr($doc_fec,8,2),substr($doc_fec,0,4)));
            $doc_ven1=date("Y-m-d",  mktime(0,0,0,substr($doc_ven,5,2),substr($doc_ven,8,2),substr($doc_ven,0,4)));
            $lim1=mktime(0,0,0,substr($fecha,5,2),substr($fecha,8,2),substr($fecha,0,4));
            $lim2=mktime(0,0,0,substr($doc_ven1,5,2),substr($doc_ven1,8,2),substr($doc_ven1,0,4));
            $dif_fec=$lim2-$lim1;
            $dias1=$dif_fec/(60*60*24); 


            if($dias1<(-9))
            {
                $color='Estilo72';
                $nom_col='VENCIDO';
                $v_ven_t=$v_ven_t+$doc_val;

            }
            else
            {

                if($dias1>-6&$dias1<1)
                {
                    $color='Estilo76';
                    $nom_col='VENCIDO ENTRE 0 Y 5 Dias';
                    $v_v5=$v_v5+$doc_val;
                }
                else
                {
                    if($dias1>1&&$dias1<5)
                    {
                        $color='Estilo77';
                        $nom_col='PROXIMO A VENCER';
                        $v_pve=$v_pve+$doc_val;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $color='Estilo73';
                        $nom_col='SIN PENDIENTES';
                        $v_spe=$v_spe+$doc_val;         
                    }
                }
            }
            $i=$i+1;
            switch($mon)
            {
                case 1: $sim='$ '; break;
                case 2: $sim='US $ '; break;
            }



         ?>

         <tr>
           <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $i+1;?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $ter_co;?></div></td>
             <td><div align="left" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $prov;?></div></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $pl_pr; ?></div></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $doc; ?></div>
             <input name="doc<?php echo $f00;?>"  type="hidden" id="doc<?php echo $f00;?>" value="<?php echo $doc;?>"/></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($doc_val),0,"",".");?></div></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $doc_ven1;?></div></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $dias1;?></div></td>
             <td class="<?php  echo $color;?>"><div align="center"></STRONG><?php echo $nom_col;?></div></td>
           <td>
           <?php 
            if($ord_pag=='S')
            { 
              echo $ord_pag; 
            }
            else
             {  ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="or_pag<?php echo $f00;?>" id="or_pag<?php echo $f00;?>" value="S" />
                <?php } ?></td>
                <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $ord_pag_f;?></div></td>
                <td>
                <?php 
                if($ord_pag=='S')
                { ?><input name="pag<?php echo $f00;?>"  type="text" id="pag<?php echo $f00;?>" value="<?php echo $doc_val;?>" size="10"/>
                <?php } ?></td>
                <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>--> 
                 </tr>

          <?php 
            if (empty($doc_pag))
            {
                $ins="INSERT INTO orden_pago_prov(fac_nume,pago_orden,pago_fecha,pago_valor,pago_seven,pago_fecha_seven)VALUES
                ('$doc','','',0,'','')";
                $ains=odbc_exec($conn, $ins);
            }

                $ter_co1=$ter_co;
            }
            else 
            {
                    /*if ($f00>0)
                    {*/
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="13"><div align="center">
                      <table width="800" border="1">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th width="60" scope="row" class="Estilo5">Total :</th>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo72" >VENCIDO:</td>
                            <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo number_format(($v_ven_t),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo76">VENCIDO0 Y 5 Dias:</td>
                            <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo number_format(($v_v5),0,"",".");?></td>
                             <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo $prov;?></td> 
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo77">PROx. VENCER:</td>
                            <td width="130"class="Estilo5"><?php echo number_format(($v_pve),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo73">SIN PENDIENTES:</td>
                            <td width="130"class="Estilo5"><?php echo number_format(($v_spe),0,"",".");?></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                    </div></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                /*  } */
                    $v_spe=0;   $v_pve=0;   $v_v5=0;    $v_ven_t=0;//$doc_val-$v_ven;
                    $ter_co1=$ter_co;
                }

         } 
         if (!empty($nom_pr)||!empty($mon_pr))
        { ?><tr>


                    <td colspan="13"><div align="center">
                      <table width="800" border="1">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th width="60" scope="row" class="Estilo5">Total :</th>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo72" >VENCIDO:</td>
                            <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($v_ven_t),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo76">VENCIDO0 Y 5 Dias:</td>
                            <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($v_v5),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo77">PROx. VENCER:</td>
                            <td width="130"class="Estilo5"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($v_pve),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo73">SIN PENDIENTES:</td>
                            <td width="130"class="Estilo5"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($v_spe),0,"",".");?></td>                   

                              </tr>
                            </tbody><td class=""><?php echo $prov;?></td>
                          </table>
                            </div></td>
                        </tr>

                     </tbody>
     </table></td>
     <?php $v_spe=0;    $v_pve=0;   $v_v5=0;    $v_ven_t=0; } ?>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="4">

    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
         <td colspan="4" align="center" >
         <input name="cuantos"  type="hidden" id="cuantos" value="<?php echo $f00;?>"/>
         <input name="formulario"  type="hidden" id="formulario" value="orden_pago"/>
         <input name="Guardar" type="submit" id="Guardar" value="Guardar" onclick="this.form.action='guardar.php'"/></td>
         </tr>
  </table>

    <?php odbc_close_all(); ?>



             <td><div align="left" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $prov;?></div></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $pl_pr; ?></div></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $doc; ?></div>
             <input name="doc<?php echo $f00;?>"  type="hidden" id="doc<?php echo $f00;?>" value="<?php echo $doc;?>"/></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($doc_val),0,"",".");?></div></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $doc_ven1;?></div></td>
             <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $dias1;?></div></td>
             <td class="<?php  echo $color;?>"><div align="center"></STRONG><?php echo $nom_col;?></div></td>
           <td>
           <?php 
            if($ord_pag=='S')
            { 
              echo $ord_pag; 
            }
            else
             {  ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="or_pag<?php echo $f00;?>" id="or_pag<?php echo $f00;?>" value="S" />
                <?php } ?></td>
                <td><div align="center" class="Estilo7"><?php echo $ord_pag_f;?></div></td>
                <td>
                <?php 
                if($ord_pag=='S')
                { ?><input name="pag<?php echo $f00;?>"  type="text" id="pag<?php echo $f00;?>" value="<?php echo $doc_val;?>" size="10"/>
                <?php } ?></td>
                <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>--> 
                 </tr>

          <?php 
            if (empty($doc_pag))
            {
                $ins="INSERT INTO orden_pago_prov(fac_nume,pago_orden,pago_fecha,pago_valor,pago_seven,pago_fecha_seven)VALUES('$doc','','',0,'','')";
                $ains=odbc_exec($conn, $ins);
            }

                $ter_co1=$ter_co;
            }
            else 
            {
                    /*if ($f00>0)
                    {*/
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="13"><div align="center">
                      <table width="800" border="1">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th width="60" scope="row" class="Estilo5">Total :</th>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo72" >VENCIDO:</td>
                            <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo number_format(($v_ven_t),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo76">VENCIDO0 Y 5 Dias:</td>
                            <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo number_format(($v_v5),0,"",".");?></td>
                             <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo $prov;?></td> 
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo77">PROx. VENCER:</td>
                            <td width="130"class="Estilo5"><?php echo number_format(($v_pve),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo73">SIN PENDIENTES:</td>
                            <td width="130"class="Estilo5"><?php echo number_format(($v_spe),0,"",".");?></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                    </div></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                /*  } */
                    $v_spe=0;   $v_pve=0;   $v_v5=0;    $v_ven_t=0;//$doc_val-$v_ven;
                    $ter_co1=$ter_co;
                }

         } 
         if (!empty($nom_pr)||!empty($mon_pr))
        { ?><tr>


                    <td colspan="13"><div align="center">
                      <table width="800" border="1">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th width="60" scope="row" class="Estilo5">Total :</th>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo72" >VENCIDO:</td>
                            <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($v_ven_t),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo76">VENCIDO0 Y 5 Dias:</td>
                            <td width="130" class="Estilo5"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($v_v5),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo77">PROx. VENCER:</td>
                            <td width="130"class="Estilo5"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($v_pve),0,"",".");?></td>
                            <td width="80" class="Estilo73">SIN PENDIENTES:</td>
                            <td width="130"class="Estilo5"><?php echo $sim; echo number_format(($v_spe),0,"",".");?></td>                   

                              </tr>
                            </tbody><td class=""><?php echo $prov;?></td>
                          </table>
                            </div></td>
                        </tr>

                     </tbody>
     </table></td>
     <?php $v_spe=0;    $v_pve=0;   $v_v5=0;    $v_ven_t=0; } ?>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="4">

    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
         <td colspan="4" align="center" >
         <input name="cuantos"  type="hidden" id="cuantos" value="<?php echo $f00;?>"/>
         <input name="formulario"  type="hidden" id="formulario" value="orden_pago"/>
         <input name="Guardar" type="submit" id="Guardar" value="Guardar" onclick="this.form.action='guardar.php'"/></td>
         </tr>
  </table>

    <?php odbc_close_all(); ?>
```

---

Esta es la imagen de referencia[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa, no es clara la pregunta. Las dos últimas filas no deberían estar? Si pudiéramos ver una muestra de datos (o datos falsos) que estás usando para pintar, sería más fácil entender qué es lo que buscas que suceda

Comment: Hola! la verdad es que soy nueva por aqui y no comprendo muy bien el tema de los comentarios ya que no me deja cargar imagenes como respuesta, pero igual la idea es que al  momento de cargar solamente me aparezcan los resultados de la primera fila, pero las otras dos que aparecen alli no se de donde las esta tomando :S

Comment: Para añadir info a la pregunta, usa el enlace editar que esta justo debajo. Ojalá siempre como texto, que desde móvil es mucho más difícil ver imagenes. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.